# Visual Studio Code snake_case word selection like IntelliJ Camel Humps

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I am developing Wordpress themes. Wordpress developers prefer snake_case coding. Is there any feature like IntelliJ camel humps word selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are these two unbound commnads for selecting word-parts, like snake_case.

```
cursorWordPartLeftSelect
cursorWordPartRightSelect

cursorWordPartStartLeftSelect
```

And there are a few more commands for moving between word parts, but not selecting them.  Just search for "wordpart" in the keyboard shortcuts.

Perhaps keybindings such as:

```
 {
    "key": "alt+right",
    "command": "cursorWordPartRight",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+left",
    "command": "cursorWordPartLeft",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+right",
    "command": "cursorWordPartRightSelect"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+left",
    "command": "cursorWordPartLeftSelect"
  }
```

[image: word_part_select]